# Custom shell with multi pipe support

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I am trying to build a custom shell in c that can support multi pipeing.

When i run a command with some pipes in it it wont work.

My suspicion is that my `execute_pipeline` function is wrong, maybe I am not closing the pipes on time or maybe I am providing the wrong file descriptors to the `execute_command` function.

This is my `execute_pipeline` function:

```
void execute_pipeline(char *args[MAX_ARGS], int n_args)
{
    char *pipe_args[MAX_PIPES][MAX_ARGS];
    int pipe_fds[MAX_PIPES][2];
    int n_pipes = 0, n_comm = 0;
    memset(pipe_args, 0, sizeof(pipe_args));
    for (int i = 0; i < n_args; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(args[i], "|") == 0)
        {
            if (n_pipes >= MAX_PIPES)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: too many pipes\n");
                return;
            }
            n_pipes++;
            n_comm = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            pipe_args[n_pipes][n_comm % MAX_ARGS] = args[i];
            pipe_args[n_pipes][n_comm % MAX_ARGS + 1] = NULL;
            n_comm++;
        }
    }
    memset(pipe_fds,0,sizeof(pipe_fds));
    // Create pipes
    for (int i = 0; i <= n_pipes; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(pipe_fds[i]) == -1)
        {
            perror("pipe");
            return;
        }
        // Determine inputfds
        int input_fd = (i == 0) ? STDIN_FILENO : pipe_fds[i-1][1];
        // Execute command
        execute_command(pipe_args[i], input_fd, pipe_fds[i][1]);
        // Close pipe fds if not needed
        if (i>0)
        {
            close(pipe_fds[i-1][0]);
            close(pipe_fds[i-1][1]);
        }
    }  
}
```

If it helps this is my `execute_command` function:

```
void execute_command(char *args[MAX_ARGS], int input_fd, int output_fd)
{
    // Fork to execute command
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    { // Child process
        // Set signal handler for SIGINT (Ctrl+C)
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);

        // Redirect input/output if necessary
        if (input_fd != STDIN_FILENO)
        {
            if (dup2(input_fd, STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
            {
                perror("dup2");
                exit(1);
            }
            close(input_fd);
        }
        if (output_fd != STDOUT_FILENO)
        {
            if (dup2(output_fd, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
            {
                perror("dup2");
                exit(1);
            }
            close(output_fd);
        }

        // Execute command
        execvp(args[0], args);
        perror("execvp");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Wait for child process to complete
    int status;
    wait(&status);
}
```

This function is working fine when i try to run single command like `ls -l` so the problem is not that this function does not run commands right.

for refrence here is a link to the full code in github [here](https://github.com/AchiyaBenNatan/stshell) .

I tryied to run a command with 3 pipes that uses the other pipes as a refrence.

here is the terminal:

```
vboxuser@Achiya:~/Desktop/stshell$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
vboxuser@Achiya:~/Desktop/stshell$ ./stshell
stshell> cat check.txt | sort | uniq > cmp_sort_uniq.txt
sort: read failed: -: Bad file descriptor
uniq: '>': No such file or directory
```

As you see the pipeing does not work properly.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: For debugging, add a *lot* of `printf` statements in your code, printing all the information possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My suspicion is that my execute_pipeline function is wrong, maybe I am not closing the pipes on time or maybe I am providing the wrong file descriptors to the execute_command function.

Your suspicion is quite right. First, the write end of a pipe instead of the read end is assigned to `input_fd`. Second, the output of the final command in the pipeline is not to go into a pipe; correct:

```
        // Determine input/output fds
        int input_fd = (i == 0) ? STDIN_FILENO : pipe_fds[i-1][0];  // read end
        pipe_fds[n_pipes][1] = STDOUT_FILENO;
```

Third, the parent shell must close the write end of a pipe before the next command in the pipeline is forked; correct:

```
        // Close pipe fds if not needed
        if (i > 0)
            close(pipe_fds[i-1][0]);
        if (i < n_pipes)
            close(pipe_fds[i][1]);
```